# What does てたも mean?

Tags: usage, sentence-final-particles

In an anime series called "Ojarumaru", the title character sometimes ends his sentences with てたも. I can't really figure out what it means. Here are some dialogue examples from the show:

> 助けてたも!
>
> おねがいじゃもう一つ作ってたも。
>
> エンマに「よいシャク見つかってよかったの」とつたえてたも。

Comment: Are you sure he said も and not もん?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

助けてたも ＝ 助けてください。

ーてたも means ください and was used throughout the [Heian period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heian_period) by *important, respected or distinguished* people.

The character おじゃる丸 uses てたも because he is a 5-year-old Heian-era prince.

Answer (score 8):

[たも](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/139069/m0u/) is 音変化 of たもれ, meaning ください. たもれ is the command form of [たもる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/139097/m0u/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%82%E3%82%8B/), which is 音変化 of [たまわる](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/138937/m0u/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B/).

> 助けてたも! ≒ 助けてたもれ, 助けてください
>   おねがいじゃもう一つ作ってたも。≒　作ってたもれ, 作ってください
>   エンマに「よいシャク見つかってよかったの」とつたえてたも。≒ つたえてたもれ, 伝えてください

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, たもれ/たも is kind of very archaic expression, and it's only spoken by Heian Era aristocrats in manga/anime (like Ojarumaru!), novels or TV shows. So, be careful not to use this in your 21st century real life :)